# How to view/download the sent fax using RingCentral Fax API C#

Tags: attachment, fax, ringcentral

Could you help me with RingCentral Fax API. I need C# code to download attachments sent via Fax. I'm using sandbox account and I found this API in API Explorer:

`/restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/message-store/{messageId}/content/{attachmentId}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the RingCentral C-Sharp SDK you can download the binary content as shown below:

```
RestClient rc = new RestClient("ClientID", "ClientSecret", false);
await rc.Authorize("username", "extensionNumber", "password");
...
var extension = rc.Restapi().Account().Extension();
var messages = response.records;
// fax
var message = messages.Where(m => m.type == "Fax" && m.messageStatus != "SendingFailed" && m.attachments != null && m.attachments.Length > 0).Skip(3).First();
var content = await extension.MessageStore(message.id).Content(message.attachments[0].id).Get();
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("filename.ext", content.data);
```

See detailed sample code from [here](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-csharp-client/blob/master/RingCentral.Test/BinaryTest.cs)

Answer (score 0):

You can Download using `WebClient` Class.
Sample Code For Your Reference.

**Code:**

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer Access_Token");
File.WriteAllBytes(@"Path To Download", client.DownloadData(URL));
```

Note: URL is `restapi/v1.0/account/AccountID/extension/extension ID/message-store/Message ID/content/Message ID`

Comment: Please, improve the code formatting of your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I will definitely improve my coding format style.